# ERROR ITMS-90034: Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Missing or invalid signature

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

I am trying to upload my react-native project on Xcode 11.3.1 to the App store and keep running into the error: Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'com.sampleapp.sample' at bundle path 'Payload/sampleapp.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate.

Screenshot 1

[image]

I downloaded my valid Apple Distribution Certificate (Sample App Certificate) into Keychain with its private key installed. In "Signing & Capabilities", I am logged into my Team developer account and set my provisioning profile to 'Sample App Profile' whose certificate matches Sample App Certificate.
I have tried restarting Xcode and there has been no fix. I have tried both automatic and manual signing and both lead to issues. Automatic signing leads to replicating certificates when trying to Validate App.

Screenshot 2

[image]

Screenshot 3

[image]